# List-box inside a list-box in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a list-box inside a list-box like this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2B3643" Opacity="1"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox2">
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I tried to bind the inner list-box, I wasn't able to do so.

The c# code that I tried is as follows.

```
List<Person> p = new List<Person>();

Person student = new Person();
student.Name = "Name1";
student.Number = "Number1";
p.Add(student);

Person teacher = new Person();
teacher.Name = "Name2";
teacher.Number = "Number2";
p.Add(teacher);

listBox2.ItemsSource = p; // cannot access listBox2
```

But I cannot access listBox2 from the xaml.cs code. It says listBox2 is not found. Also I want to bind the listBox2 only when the button is clicked and not when binding listBox1. Can someone tell me how do I access listBox2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding listbox in listbox on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735905/binding-listbox-in-listbox-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 2):

You have added listBox2 inside the `DataTemplate` of listBox1. So it won't be accessible in the code behind. To elaborate, consider you have item1, item2 and item3 in listBox1. Then you will have an object of ListBox named listBox2 in item1, item2 and item3. You cannot specifically point one of these objects in the code behind. One way to achieve the binding is, you create a list inside the items that you have bound to listBox1 and bind it to the inner `ListBox`.

```
List<Item> MainList = new List<Item>();

class Item
{
   List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();
}


<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource = "{Binding MainList}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      ...
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource= "{Binding PersonList}">
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  ...
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note: Refer this related question - [Binding listbox in listbox on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735905/binding-listbox-in-listbox-on-windows-phone-8/29739503#29739503)