# Binding Data in Listbox Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

How i can bind two list box item source in single page Windows Phone? I mean:

- Case 1: I have a json url and I get a response and so in listbox is ok
- Case 2: When a user will tap the selected item and I have one more json url, the response will show on same page inside of selected item.

  ```
  <ListBox Name="list_contact"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResults" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding service_name, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResult" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding fname , Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Margin="10, 20, 0, 0" />
                      </StackPanel>
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the readability. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: Is this what you require? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162330/list-box-inside-a-list-box-in-c-sharp/30162584#30162584